# remove rows from dataframe where contents could be a choice of strings

Tags: python, pandas

so i can do something like:

```
data = df[ df['Proposal'] != 'C000' ]
```

to remove all Proposals with string C000, but how can i do something like:

```
data = df[ df['Proposal'] not in ['C000','C0001' ]
```

to remove all proposals that match either C000 or C0001 (etc. etc.)

Comment: Use `~` and `isin`  `df.loc[~df.Proposal.isin(['C000', 'C0001'])]`

Comment: Could be there more than 2 exclude items in your case?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
df = df.drop(df[df['Proposal'].isin(['C000','C0001'])].index)
```

Or to select the required ones,

```
df = df[~df['Proposal'].isin(['C000','C0001'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
data = df.loc[np.logical_not(df['Proposal'].isin({'C000','C0001'})), :]
# or
data = df.loc[              ~df['Proposal'].isin({'C000','C0001'}) , :]
```

Comment: Can you explain how your answer works?

Comment: `isin` checks if values of the Series is in some set (aka 'in'), `np.logical_not` or `~` negate it (aka 'not in'), and `loc` selects rows of a DataFrame using boolean array.